# How to host static content from Jboss EAP 7.1 slave in HA cluster?

Tags: load-balancing, jboss7.x, high-availability, jboss-eap-7, static-content

I have JBoss running in clustered mode. I access the application via load balancer URL. As per specifications, JBoss EAP 7.1 serves the static content from welcome-content directory. I have a file which is under slave's welcome-content. It is not getting accessed via load balancer URL. If the file is on master with same name, it is accessible. Can I have such condition in place that if the same name file is not found on master, it will serve the file from slave instead of 404.

Any help is much appreciated.